# If the y-coordinates are arranged in descending order, how would one calculate the difference in x-coordinates?

Tags: c

Description

> During their honeymoon, Mrs and Mr Smith went to the Himalayas. How they were surprised when
> they observed that, during the sunset, all the snow touched by the sunbeams turned red.
> Such a magnificent landscape leaves everyone plenty of emotion, but Mr Smith’s number obsession
> overcame all this. He rapidly began evaluating distances, which made Mrs Smith quite upset.
>
> Your work is to help him calculate the size, in meters, of the mountainsides that became red as the
> sun sets. Mr Smith’s honeymoon depends on you! Please be quick and efficient.
>
> For the sake of simplicity, consider that, during the sunset, the sunbeams are horizontal and assume
> that the landscape is described by the set of coordinates of the mountain peaks and cols. This can be
> depicted by the following figure. A landscape, in this context, is then a sequence of peaks and cols (i.e.,
> only a col follows a peak and conversely).
>
> image.png
>
> Note that, in this picture, the sunny mountainsides are emphasized by bold lines and the coordinates
> of the landscape are emphasized by bold points.
>
> Thus, the goal of this problem is to calculate the total length in meters of the bold lines.
> For this task consider that: (1) for all coordinates (x, y), 0 ≤ x ≤ 30000 and 0 ≤ y ≤ 8848; (2)
> the unit is the meter; (3) all the X-coordinates are pair-wise distinct; (4) the leftmost point has 0 as
> X-coordinate and the rightmost point has 0 as Y-coordinate; (5) The total number of coordinates given
>
> Input
>
> The first line of input contains C (0 < C < 100), the number of test cases that follows.
>
> Each test case starts with a line containing the number N of coordinate pairs. The remaining N
> lines for each test case contain the coordinates defining the landscape. Each of these lines contains two
> integers, x and y, separated by a single space. The first integer, x, is the X-coordinate, and the second,
> y, is the Y-coordinate of the considered point.
>
> Output
>
> The output is formed by a sequence of lines, one for each test case. Each line contains a single real
> number with exactly two decimal digits. This number represents the length in meters of the sunny
> mountainsides for the corresponding test case.
>
> Sample Input 1
>
> ```
> 2
> 11
> 1100 1200
> 0 500
> 1400 100
> 600 600
> 2800 0
> 400 1100
> 1700 600
> 1500 800
> 2100 300
> 1800 700
> 2400 500
> 2
> 0 1000
> 1000 0
> ```
>
> Sample Output 1
>
> ```
> 1446.34
> 1414.21
> ```

My idea is to use a 2D array (e.g., v[100][2], where v[100][0] stores the x-coordinate and v[100][1] stores the y-coordinate). Then, I want to compare the y-coordinates: placing the larger ones at the front and the smaller ones at the end using bubble sort. If the y-coordinate inside the array is greater than the second-to-last one, then the total length is the sum of the previous length plus the square root of the distance between the last two points [(x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2], plus the distance between the second-to-last point and the last point [sqrt(x^2 + y^2)]. However, I'm wondering how to calculate the difference in x-coordinates using this method, or if there's a flaw in the logic. Could someone please correct me?

Here is the code I've attempted to write:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int c,n,v[100][2],temp_x,temp_y;
    scanf("%d",&c);

    while(c--){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d %d",&v[i][0],&v[i][1]);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<n-1-i;j++){
                if(v[j+1][1]>v[j][1]){
                    temp_x = v[j+1][0];
                    temp_y = v[j+1][1];
                    v[j+1][1] = v[j][1];
                    v[j+1][0] = v[j][0];
                    v[j][1] = temp_y;
                    v[j][0] = temp_x;
                }
            }
        }

        double sum=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            if(v[i][1]>v[n-1][1]){
                sum+=sqrt((v[i][1]-v[i+1][1])*(v[i][1]-v[i+1][1])+(v[i][0]-v[i+1][0])*(v[i][0]-v[i+1][0]));//+sqrt(v[n-2][1]*v[n-2][1]+(v[n-1][0]-v[n-1][0])*(v[n-1][0]-v[n-1][0]));
            }
        } 
        printf("%.2lf\n",sum);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bubblesort is at best a teaching exercise for algorithms in general.  As a sort algorithm it sucks.  The C standard library includes [`qsort()`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/); no need to write your own if that is not the primary purpose of the exercise.

Comment: Apart from that, your question lacks focus. To be honest TL;DR. You have dumped the entire exercise (apart from the image), and presented some code without asking a specific question about your solution.  What result does your code produce? What result do you expect?  How do they differ?  Is it the "logic" or rather the _math_ that concerns you?